# Pointer to fixed value vs pointer with fixed address

Tags: c++, c

The statement `const int* p = &a;` gives a pointer to a fixed value.  While `p` itself can be assigned to a different address (e.g. `p = &b;`), we cannot change the dereferenced value (e.g. `*p  = 100;` gives a compile error).

I get that.

How can I define a pointer with a fixed address in that it cannot be reassigned?  I mean if `p2 = &a;` then `p2 = &b;` should give a compile error.

Comment: Please tag only one language. C and C++ are different languages with different rules.

Comment: `const int* const p2 = &a`?